# Retryable annotation is not working in spring batch application

Tags: spring, spring-batch

This is my class where i call one service .
This is the code that i am tying

I have enabled retry on the class level as well .
Do i have to do anything else in order to make this work ..

This is from my production spring application .The above one is just where i was trying to run locally .

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts=2 ,value=NotFoundException.class,backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10000,multiplier=2))
private boolean extractVesselDetailsFromSOL(String imoNumber) {
    try{
        Entity result = nameMatcherRestClient.getEntity(VESSEL_PREFIX + imoNumber);
        if (result != null) {
            addVesselDetailsToMap(result, imoNumber);
            addAssociateDetailsToMap(result, imoNumber);
        }
    }catch(NotFoundException e){
        LOGGER.error("Exception in extractVesselDetailsFromSOL :: "+e.getMessage());
        LOGGER.error("Exception in extractVesselDetailsFromSOL :: "+Count++);
        System.out.println("NameMatcher --> " + Count++);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And this is one the place where i am calling the above method

```
private boolean getVesselDetails(String imoNumber){
    return ((!vesselDetailsFromSol.containsKey(imoNumber)) && (!extractVesselDetailsFromSOL(imoNumber)));
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a Spring Application: you are instantiating the NameProcessor class, instead of invoking it as a bean from the application context

Comment: @codependent this i have written to test it Locally because i wont be able to put full working class here ..If you want i can put specific method but will that help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your updated question I think I know what the problem is: you're invoking `extractVesselDetailsFromSOL` from within the same bean (it's a private method). @Retryable methods need to be invoked from different beans so that the AOP (retry) functionality can kick in. You should refactor you code to something like:

```
public class SomeBean {

    @Autowired
    private SomeOtherBean someOtherBean;

    public someOperation() {
        ...
        someOtherBean.extractVesselDetailsFromSOL(xxx);
    }
}

public class SomeOtherBean {

    @Retryable(maxAttempts=2 ,value=NotFoundException.class,backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10000,multiplier=2))
    public boolean extractVesselDetailsFromSOL(String imoNumber) {
        try{
            Entity result = nameMatcherRestClient.getEntity(VESSEL_PREFIX + imoNumber);
            if (result != null) {
                addVesselDetailsToMap(result, imoNumber);
                addAssociateDetailsToMap(result, imoNumber);
            }
        }catch(NotFoundException e){
            LOGGER.error("Exception in extractVesselDetailsFromSOL :: "+e.getMessage());
            LOGGER.error("Exception in extractVesselDetailsFromSOL :: "+Count++);
            System.out.println("NameMatcher --> " + Count++);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-pointcuts-designators):

> Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, **calls within
>   the target object are by definition not intercepted**. For JDK proxies,
>   **only public interface method calls on the proxy can be intercepted**.
>   With CGLIB, public and protected method calls on the proxy will be
>   intercepted, and even package-visible methods if necessary. However,
>   common interactions through proxies should always be designed through
>   public signatures.
>
> Note that pointcut definitions are generally matched against any
>   intercepted method. If a pointcut is strictly meant to be public-only,
>   even in a CGLIB proxy scenario with potential non-public interactions
>   through proxies, it needs to be defined accordingly.
>
> If your interception needs include method calls or even constructors
>   within the target class, consider the use of Spring-driven native
>   AspectJ weaving instead of Spring’s proxy-based AOP framework. This
>   constitutes a different mode of AOP usage with different
>   characteristics, so be sure to make yourself familiar with weaving
>   first before making a decision.

Someone with the same problem as you [asked on Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/55) and the solution was what I've shown above: make that functionality available from one bean and invoked from another.

Comment: Sorry i did not get Different bean means ? I have updated the place my method is called